# Html tags are getting printed as it are.... heredoc is not working

Tags: html, printing, tags

Html tags printed as they are.

My code:

`$this->frontend_model->get_frontend_general_settings('about_us')` contains string content along with html tags like `<br>`

```
    <?php echo <<<HTML $this->frontend_model- 
   >get_frontend_general_settings('about_us') HTML; ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is exactly not working? What's the result? And do you expect? Please specify your question!

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what your code does, but if you don't tell us what your expected outcome is there is no way to help! Give us some more info and I'm sure someone will be able to help you